# Right and left continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose we want to show that a function $f$ with domain interval $[a,b]$ is right-continuous at $a$ and left-continuous at $b$.

If we also know that $f$ is increasing then is it sufficient to show that:

$$f(a)\geq\inf_{x>a}f(x)\quad\text{and}\quad f(b)\leq\sup_{x<b}f(x)?$$

I am not sure why that is true. Why does increasing matter in this case?

I'd appreciate any help or hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is more general than what you write.

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is increasing and satisfies $f(b)\leq\sup_{x<b}f(x)$ for some point $b$ in the domain of $f$.
Then, for each $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that $f(b-\delta)+\epsilon\geq f(b)$ or, equivalently, $f(b)-f(b-\delta)\leq\epsilon$.
Since $f$ is increasing, it follows that $f(b)-f(b^{\prime})\leq\epsilon$ for all $b^{\prime}$ such that $b-b^{\prime}\leq\delta$, establishing left-continuity.

Comment: Could you please explain why $f(b)\leq\sup_{x<b}f(x)$ is sufficient for left-continuity?

Comment: My answer is a proof of why it is sufficient ;-) Maybe there's a specific part of the proof you don't understand that you can tell me to elaborate on?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your proof. I am aware of the left-cont. definition $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}f(x)=f(b)$ and unfortunately I cannot see the connection with the supremum.

Comment: The proof assumes the condition $f(b) \leq \sup_{x < b} f(x)$ (see the first sentence) and establishes the limiting condition you wrote in your comment (see the last sentence).

Answer (score 0):

$\underset{x\rightarrow a^+}{\lim}f(x)$ is monotone decreasing so if it is bounded below it will converge.  It is bounded below by f(a) so it converges by monotone convergence theorem.  If $\underset{x\rightarrow a^+}{\lim}f(x) = L$ then $L = \underset{x\rightarrow a^+}{\liminf}f(x) \leq f(a)$, but by virtue of incre f, $\underset{x\rightarrow a^+}{\liminf}f(x)\geq f(a)\implies \underset{x\rightarrow a^+}{\liminf}f(x) = f(a) = L$. Thus $\underset{x\rightarrow a^+}{\lim}f(x) = f(a)$. Same argument applies to the other side.

Comment: I think it will be more helpful if you edit your answer by formatting mathjax correctly in order to make the answer readable.

Comment: just amended for clarity, hope that helps.